# VS2008, Debugging, Local IIS Server vs Use Custom Web Server, SSL/https

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis-7, https

I am debugging a vs2008 web application project using the custom web server option and some of the pages are using https.  I can debug https pages. Using iis7/Vista.

The way I'm doing it is:

- name of the self signed certificate is assigned to trucks
- custom server url: http://trucks
- hosts file: 127.0.0.1 trucks
- publish to http://trucks

I would think another way to do the same thing is to:

- make a self signed certificate assigned to localhost
- use the Local IIS Server option.

What is the difference between the two in terms of debugging and security?

The way I'm doing it now, I like not having localhost in the url, since http://trucks will more closely simulate the production environment.  I also plan to implement custom url rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not difference in terms of debugging and security.

But IMO, your approach (using **trucks**) is the best way, because with a localhost certificate you could be mistakenly be using other certificate installed to other site in the same machine.